# Applying for a lecturership. What should I write in "supporting statement" through the on-line application?

Tags: application, lecturer

I have already prepared my CV, my cover letter, my research and teaching plans, as well as a document with my previous research overview.

When applying through the university website, there is a mandatory "supporting statement" box to fill (max 2000 characters). "State your reasons for applying and why you meet the specifications".

It seems sort of obvious what I should write there, but that would be duplicating what I said in my cover letter, because it is basically the same.

Should I copy my cover letter there? That would be like redudant info, and also kind of lazy. But just rephrasing my cover letter also is kind of redundant.

What should I write there?

Thanks!

Comment: _Should I copy my cover letter there?_ — I strongly suspect that their requested "supporting statement" is precisely what you're thinking of as a "cover letter".  (The actual cover letter doesn't need to be anything more than a brief introduction, a complete list of the materials you've submitted, and the names and contact information for your references.)